# How to update the JProgressBar after receiving the bytes from Socket with java?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to build a browser with java with a `JProgressBar` for a few days.
So I can get the bytes from Socket like this:

```
    try {

         Socket s = new Socket("target.com", 80);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
         out.println("GET /page HTTP/1.1");
         out.println("Host: target.com");
         out.println();
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

How can I update the `JProgressBar` to set the internet page in a `JEditorPane`?

Comment: What you tried so far to achieve your goal and what are the problems?

Comment: The problem that i don't know to update the jprogressbar after recieving the bytes from socket

Comment: So you have looked at JProgressBar api? Tried some examples, got some errors?

Comment: yes! it's do many errors

Comment: Good! Can you update your question with the code you've tried and the errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile here a very simple working example. All credits go to [zentut](http://www.zentut.com/java-swing/jprogressbar/)

It should get you started with basic JProgressBar setup.

```
package jprogressbardemo;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX = 100;
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JProgress Demo");

        // creates progress bar
        final JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();


        pb.setMinimum(0);
        pb.setMaximum(MAX);
        pb.setStringPainted(true);

        // add progress bar
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(pb);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // update progressbar
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
            final int currentValue = i;
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setValue(currentValue);
                    }
                });
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```